# youtube-dl to dl according to batch file of keywords instead of urls

Tags: linux, command-line, youtube-dl

I have been trying to get youtube-dl to download search results, from a batch file.

I am able to specify key words for individual searches like:

youtube-dl -i -w "ytsearch:67 Mustang Repair -l 5"

I am also able to get youtube-dl to batch download a list of URLs
youtube-dl -i -w -a batch_file_of_urls.txt

but I have not been able to successfully use ytsearch to download according to a list of keywords.

I have tried using pipes variations like cat batch_file_of_urls.txt | youtube-dl etc but thats apparently just rubish.

I know the mod said my post was too vauge but I am honestly not sure how to make it more specific as I do not know how, if youtube-dl does not accept batch keyword lists, to say feed a list of keywords into youtube-dl, using > or | ?

Comment: Well, [the docs](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#filesystem-options) explicitly say that the batch file option is for lists of URLs only. But if the non-batch search option works for you, why don't you just run it in a loop? You can even use something like [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) to speed it up if your usecase requires it.